# Java reflection - non case sensitive Class.forName() in a package

Tags: java, class, reflection, package, case-sensitive

The same question already has answers for [`fields`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351108/java-reflection-ignore-case-when-using-getdeclaredfield) and [`methods`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737388/problem-using-model-getclass-getmethod-in-case-of-inheritance), both suggesting to iterate over the existing members and lower-case comparing the names. But `classes` are different in that you can't [[easily]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) iterate over classes in a package.

My java application instantiates objects according to a given input from a 3rd party - non-case-sensitive - application, and it fails when the case is wrong. Since java won't allow classes with same name and different case in one package, I guess there should be a simple way to get a `Class` object without having the exact case.

I want to avoid multiple `if`/`else if` since I add classes to the package all the time.
`try`ing all case possibilities is also out of question (since it is O(2^n)).

So, how should I go about it?

**Solution:**

As suggested in [@IReeder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19281951/1609201) (thanks @assylias), I Ignored standard Java conventions and name all your classes lowercase. This way I can always call class.forName with the lower case version of the input.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281781/quick-fix-for-class-forname-case-issue

Comment: Now I did. Naming all classes in lower case might be a good solution.