# Ignore case-sensitive "methodName" for getting a method of a Class in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I want to get a Method of a Class in this Way:

```
int value = 5;
Class paramType = value.getClass();
String MethodName = "myMethod";
Class<?> theClass = obj.getClass();
Method m = theClass.getMethod(MethodName, paramType);
```

Is it possible to ignore `MethodName` case-sensitive?
For example, if there is a method in `theClass` with name `foo`, how can I 
find it with having `MethodName=fOO`?

Comment: No, Java is case sensitive so it is possible to have two separate methods like `foo(String s)` and `Foo(String s)` in the same class. You need to provide your own implementation and handle this case.

Comment: [Get all methods and check them yourself, like for fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351108/java-reflection-ignore-case-when-using-getdeclaredfield). There is no onboard `getMethodsCaseInsensitive` feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is case sensitive, so there's no such built-in method. You could, however, implement it yourself by iterating over all the methods and checking their names and parameter types:

```
public List<Method> getMethodsIgnoreCase
    (Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Class<?> paramType) {

    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods())
                 .filter(m -> m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName))
                 .filter(m -> m.getParameterTypes().length ==  1)
                 .filter(m -> m.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(paramType))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note:
This method looks for a method with a single argument that matches the given type, to match the requirement in the OP. It can easily be generalized to receive a list/array of argument types though.